# Reading a file with fixed size column

Tags: perl, cgi

using perl CGI  I'm trying to read from a file with fixed width columns and insert each column value into an array.
I thought to rea the file per line and then with substr extract each column.
The number of column is fixed and each column has a different width, space is always separating 2 columns but blank space are also used inside the column values an example below (4 column)

```
this is filed1       field2   this is nextfield3 field4
line2field1          l2field2 field3             and field4 line2
first field          second   third              fourth
```

The problem is when i read the file the multiple space are automatically replaced by a single space see the example below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; 
use diagnostics;
use warnings;
my $file="example.txt";
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file)  or die "Could not open file '$file' $!";      
while (my $ll =<$fh>) {
    print "<br>line is $ll";
}
close $fh;
```

The output of this (assuming example.txt is the one above) is:

```
this is filed1 field2 this is nextfield3 field4
line2field1 l2field2 field3 and field4 line2
first field second third fourth
```

and this do not really allow me to use substr to manipulate the string using the known fixed width.
Any idea why it's happening and how I can read the file keeping the extra spaced between fields?
I also opened the file with text editor like notepad++ to make sure the extra space were not due to special character and I can confirm they are just blank spaces.

Comment: Bareword "example" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./1.pl line 5.
Bareword "txt" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./1.pl line 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spaces are still there, but they are rendered as one space by the browser. Use `<pre>` to display them exactly as in the input.